# How to support multiple domains on one Web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system, .htaccess, lamp

I've set up an Ubuntu 10.04 LAMP server. I am going to set up multiple domains so that they will point to this server's IP. How to configure the server so, that it will serve a specific site (placed in a specific folder) according to a domain name which was used in the request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use name-based virtual hosts, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html